# Running Javascript and Servlets code in a package

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

Hi I am working on a project, wherein I have done backend changes in a XYZ package. Now I have to work on making some UI changes, which include another package, which has ".js" files (index.js) for UI, a server.jsp file, and sub pacakges having the .java files. One of the sub pacakge is Servlets package.

I know this is a very trivial question, but I donot know the working of servlets at all. I know basic web-development, but not the server end.

I just need to ask, how to run the code in this pacakge, running the index.jsp file using server.jsp file, on my desktop(using my system as server).

Can anyone please tell how I can do that, by making some changes or how to access on the browser?

Comment: Perhaps, `WEB-INF` folder ?

Comment: Yeah it has WEB-INF folder, with web.xml also. I do not know basically how to start tomcat server. I am using eclipse.

Comment: web.xml have servlet names and the respective url-pattern. Do I have to run "hhtp://myDesktopname/servletName" ? or before doing this, I think I need to start the tomacat server right?

Comment: You are confused at several levels. At package level, http level, url level, and file access level.

Comment: i know, could you help in clearing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

1) Forget about your desktop.

2) You just write your Java Servlets along with your normal Java classes. Any ways you give the full path in your web.xml.

3)Place all your JSP/JS files in WEB-INF.

4)Once all done, Make a war file of your project.

5) In your web-xml configure the welcome file list.

6) Once you place your war file in your tomcat, start the tomcat.

7) once you start your tomcat, hit the application with the url like

```
http://localhost:8080/your_war_name/
```

That redirects you to the page you configure to the welcome file in the web.xml.

Hope that helps.